Cannot get WooCommerce submit order to wait for user confirmation
I am attempting to call an API at the moment that my users hit the "submit order" button in my WooCommerce shop. The order should wait for an API response and wait for the user to confirm in a popup modal before submitting.
Instead, it seems to not be waiting for either. The API call happens to complete first, and then the user confirmation popup displays, but before the user can interact with the modal, the order submits and we are redirected to another page.
I have tried "event.preventDefault()" but that doesn't seem to be preventing the form submission and page redirection. I have also tried unhooking everything attached to the woocommerce_review_order_after_submit and woocommerce_checkout_process hooks in an attempt to stop the submit button from working. Any insight would be legendary
below is a simplified version of my code

async function validateAddress() {
    // Construct the request body
    const requestBody = JSON.stringify({
        address: {
            regionCode: 'us',
            postalCode: 01234,
            administrativeArea: 'someState',
            locality: 'someCity',
            addressLines: ['someAddress']
        },
    });
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/wp-content/themes/almadelic-theme/google_maps_proxy.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok ' + response.statusText);
        }
        else{
            jQuery('#addressModal').show();
        }

    } catch (error) {
        return false; // Indicating validation failed
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //Add the popup modal
    $('body').append(`
        <div id="addressModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p id="modalMessage">${message}</p>
                <br>
                <div id="buttonContainer">
                        <button id="confirmButton">Yes, this address is correct</button>
                        <button id="changeButton">No, let me change the address</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `);
    

    if (typeof validateAddress === 'function') {
        $(document).on('click', '.wc-block-components-checkout-place-order-button', async function(event) {
            
            event.preventDefault();             //SHOULD prevent the order from submitting
            var isValid = await validateAddress();      //This function does fire, and its modal displays, but the order submits before the user can confirm the details in the popup modal

            // Prevent form submission if validation fails
            if (!isValid) {
                alert('Please correct the address errors before placing your order.');
            } else {
                document.getElementById('checkout_form').submit();
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('validateAddress function is not found. Please verify the function name and scope.');
    }
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //Add the popup modal
    $('body').append(`
        <div id="addressModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p id="modalMessage">${message}</p>
                <br>
                <div id="buttonContainer">
                        <button id="confirmButton">Yes, this address is correct</button>
                        <button id="changeButton">No, let me change the address</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `);
    
    // Function to validate address
    async function validateAddress() {
        // Construct the request body
        const requestBody = JSON.stringify({
            address: {
                regionCode: 'us',
                postalCode: 01234,
                administrativeArea: 'someState',
                locality: 'someCity',
                addressLines: ['someAddress']
            },
        });
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/wp-content/themes/almadelic-theme/google_maps_proxy.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok ' + response.statusText);
            } else {
                return true; // Address is valid
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return false; // Indicating validation failed
        }
    }

    // Event listener for place order button
    $(document).on('click', '.wc-block-components-checkout-place-order-button', async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
        
        // Validate address
        var isValid = await validateAddress();
        
        // Display modal if address is valid
        if (isValid) {
            $('#addressModal').show();
        } else {
            alert('Please correct the address errors before placing your order.');
        }
    });

    // Event listener for confirm button in modal
    $(document).on('click', '#confirmButton', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default button behavior
        
        // Submit order form
        document.getElementById('checkout_form').submit();
    });

    // Event listener for change button in modal
    $(document).on('click', '#changeButton', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default button behavior
        
        // Hide modal or perform any other action
        $('#addressModal').hide();
    });
});


This does not address the issue described above. The issue is that prevent.default() is not preventing form submission. additionally this is an answer with code and no explanation

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
